# Code Analysis (FXCop) Command line differences

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop, static-code-analysis

We are currently running code analysis in release mode, when we run the code analysis in our dev environments, through the Visual Studio IDE  we get 2 errors :

1) CA1506   Avoid excessive class coupling

2) CA1823   Avoid unused private fields

When we check in we have a gated check in on a build server which gets the latest sources runs units tests and Code Analysis. The server does not pick up these errors.

I have checked to ensure its using the same rule-set and that the projects are not excluded from being run. The only difference is that the Build server uses the command line to run Code Analysis and not the IDE. The server does use VS2010 and we use VS2012 but I tried on another dev pc which ran VS2010 and the errors appeared, so it really seems its the command line tool...

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turns out that the issue was on the Build server we were running FxCopCmd version 10.0 and after we   upgraded to 11, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was on the Build server we were running FxCopCmd version 10.0 and after we upgraded to 11, the issue was solved.